# How do I rotate and oscillate the same object in Processing

Tags: java, animation, processing, visualization

I am creating a snowflake simulation in Processing however i am not sure how to perform more than one transformation to an image as it seems you can only perform one.

```
class Snowflake{
  float imgWidth;
  float imgHeight;
  PVector pos;
  PVector vel;
  final float firstXPos;

  float a = 0.0;
  float angularVel = 0.01;

  float x;
  float amp;
  float period;

  Snowflake(float xWidth, float yHeight){
    imgWidth = xWidth;
    imgHeight = yHeight;
    pos = new PVector(random(width), 0);
    vel = new PVector(0,1);
    firstXPos = this.pos.x;
  }
  void descend(){
    amp = 75;  
    period = 200;

    x = amp * sin((frameCount/period) * TWO_PI);
```

This is where i am trying to rotate the image and oscillate it back and forth.

```
    pushMatrix();
    translate(firstXPos,this.pos.y);
    image(snowflakeImg, x, this.pos.y, imgWidth, imgHeight);
    popMatrix();

    //creating a line for oscillation reference
    //translate(firstXPos, this.pos.y);
    //stroke(255);
    //line(0,0,x,y);

}
  void update(){
    pos.add(vel);
    a += angularVel;
  }

}
```

Here is my sketch, just loading in assets and setting up the sketch

```
PImage snowflakeImg;
Snowflake snowFlake;

void setup() {
  imageMode(CENTER);
  snowflakeImg = loadImage("snowflake.png", "png");
  snowFlake = new Snowflake(25, 25);
  size(800,600);
}

void draw(){
  background(0);
  snowFlake.descend();
  snowFlake.update();  
}
```

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve]? Try using a simple rectangle shape instead of a snowflake, so we can run your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating a single `Snowflake` instance.
You need to create more, then update each one.

In your case you should initialise an array of `Snowflake` objects first (at the top where you declare your variables). Here's an example allocating an array of 99 `Snowflake` objects:

```
int numSnowflakes = 99;
Snowflake[] snowflakes = new Snowflake[numSnowflakes];
```

Then in `setup()` you can initialise each array element as a new `Snowflake` instance:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < numSnowflakes; i++){
    snowflakes[i] = new Snowflake(25, 25);
  }
```

Finally in `draw()` you can loop through each object so it can `descend()` and `update()`:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < numSnowflakes; i++){
    snowflakes[i].descend();
    snowflakes[i].update();  
  }
```

If you're not familiar with arrays in Processing yet I can recommend the following resources:

1. [Processing arrays tutorial](https://processing.org/tutorials/arrays/)
2. [Processing ArrayObjects example](https://processing.org/examples/arrayobjects.html)
3. [Daniel Shiffman's Array of Objects Coding Train video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-sSRHRfK2EU) along with [Arrays and Loops](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=am6e1U2BHkA)

Once you've got the hang of this you should look into [ArrayList](https://processing.org/examples/arraylistclass.html) as well.

**Update**
To address your comment, you can use push/pop matrix calls to further isolate coordinate systems and rotate the image around it's centre:

```
x = amp * sin((frameCount/period) * TWO_PI);
// enter local coordinate system #1
pushMatrix();
// move to flake position
translate(firstXPos,this.pos.y);
  // enter local coordinate system #2
  pushMatrix();
    // move to updated (oscillated) x position
    translate(x, this.pos.y);
    // rotated from translated position (imageMode(CENTER) helps rotate around centre)
    rotate(frameCount * 0.1);
    // render the image at it's final transformation
    image(snowflakeImg,0,0, imgWidth, imgHeight);
  popMatrix();
popMatrix();
```

For more info check out the [Coordinate Systems Processing tutorial](https://processing.org/tutorials/drawing/).

For reference here's a test sketch I've used with each flake at random width:

```
PImage snowflakeImg;
Snowflake snowFlake;

int numSnowflakes = 99;
Snowflake[] snowflakes = new Snowflake[numSnowflakes]; 

void setup() {
  imageMode(CENTER);
  //snowflakeImg = loadImage("snowflake.png", "png");
  PGraphics snowflakeG = createGraphics(25,25);
  snowflakeG.beginDraw();
  snowflakeG.rectMode(CENTER);
  snowflakeG.rect(0,0,25,25);
  snowflakeG.endDraw();
  snowflakeImg = snowflakeG;

  for(int i = 0 ; i < numSnowflakes; i++){
    snowflakes[i] = new Snowflake(25, 25);
  }

  size(800,600);
}

void draw(){
  background(0);
  for(int i = 0 ; i < numSnowflakes; i++){
    snowflakes[i].descend();
    snowflakes[i].update();  
  }
}
class Snowflake{
  float imgWidth;
  float imgHeight;
  PVector pos;
  PVector vel;
  final float firstXPos;

  float a = 0.0;
  float angularVel = 0.01;

  float x;
  float amp;
  float period;

  Snowflake(float xWidth, float yHeight){
    imgWidth = xWidth;
    imgHeight = yHeight;
    pos = new PVector(random(width), 0);
    vel = new PVector(0,1);
    firstXPos = this.pos.x;
  }
  void descend(){
    amp = 75;  
    period = 200;

    x = amp * sin((frameCount/period) * TWO_PI);
    // enter local coordinate system #1
    pushMatrix();
    // move to flake position
    translate(firstXPos,this.pos.y);
      // enter local coordinate system #2
      pushMatrix();
        // move to updated (oscillated) x position
        translate(x, this.pos.y);
        // rotated from translated position (imageMode(CENTER) helps rotate around centre)
        rotate(frameCount * 0.1);
        // render the image at it's final transformation
        image(snowflakeImg,0,0, imgWidth, imgHeight);
      popMatrix();
    popMatrix();

    //creating a line for oscillation reference
    //translate(firstXPos, this.pos.y);
    //stroke(255);
    //line(0,0,x,y);

}
  void update(){
    pos.add(vel);
    a += angularVel;
  }

}
```

You should also check out [Daniel Shiffman's Snowfall coding challenge](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cl-mHFCGzYk).
Even though it's p5.js the same logic can be easily applied in Processing.

Comment: Thanks but what I really wanted was help in the snowflake class and in the descend function, how do I rotate the object and oscillate it from side to side at the same time

Comment: thanks for that. I tried it though and now the pos of the object is always the same and is not initiated as a random width but initiated where the oscillation occurs.

Comment: Not sure how you do that, I've added comments to the snippet above to make it easier to follow what's going on. I've also added a test sketch based on your code with slight changes as I don't load an image.

Comment: Thanks for your help but seems like this is an impossible problem, it really appreciate your help.

Comment: also, do you have to indent after the pushmatrix or is that just for visual purposes

Comment: trust me it's not an impossible task, it only seems so before it clicks mentally: it only gets easier after that. checkout the video I've linked: it will break down the logic step by step. you're 100% right: indenting is not required, it's only for visual purposes (IMO easier to scan the code and mentally visualise the coordinate systems).

Comment: Thanks for the video link, I figured it out, you just have to add the x sin wave oscillation to the translate x and then rotate. Thanks for the help.